# Firebase Authentication on iMessage extension

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can I get login credentials (sign-in method is Google) in an iMessage extension?

The [legacy documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/libraries/watchkit/guide.html) recommends sharing the user's Firebase auth token through **App Groups**, then, reading it in as a **custom token**. But, it's not a custom token and throws an error stating it's an invalid token.

I can only get this to work doing the following:

**AppDelegate.swift (target host)**

```
// **********  Beginning of the Google Sign-in *********************
public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

     if let error = error {
       print(error.localizedDescription)
      return
     }


    // ** Passing our creds to other target apps like iMessage **
    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication?.idToken)!,
                                                  accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)

    let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.pigshareData")!
    defaults.set((authentication?.idToken)!, forKey: "idToken")
    defaults.set((authentication?.accessToken)!, forKey: "accessToken")

    defaults.synchronize()
    // **  End of passing our creds **


    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
     // ...
    }
}
```

**MessagesViewController.swift (target iMessage)**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  FIRApp.configure()

  let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.pigshareData")!
  // Grab the auth token
  let authToken = defaults.object(forKey: "FAuthDataToken") as? String

  let idToken = defaults.object(forKey: "idToken") as? String
  let accessToken = defaults.object(forKey: "accessToken") as? String

  let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken!,
                                                  accessToken: accessToken!)


  FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential){ (user, error) in
       print("\(user)  \(error)")
  }

  // FIR Database stuff
  FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
  ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

}
```

**My Question**

Is this the proper way to do this?  I can't get this to work with a single token, as explained in the legacy documentation.

Note above both an `authentication?.idToken` and an `authentication?.accessToken` are passed, then, the variable `credential` is constructed from these two variables. Maybe that's the standard way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution to this one @Mike?